# Time complexity analysis. choosing operator for counting number of times a line of code runs

Tags: algorithm, analysis, pseudocode

Analysing time complexity of this pseudocode. On the right my take on the number of times each line runs. I'm not sure whether to use log n , n log n , or simply n for the while-loop..please help

```
                                times
1 sum = 0                        1
2 i = 1                          1  
3 while i ≤ n                 log n + 1
4     for j = 1 to n           n log n
5     sum = sum + j            n log n
6 i = 2i                       log n
7 return sum                     1
```

this results in: 2 n log + 2log n + 4

and thereby : O(n log n)

is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your while loop is:

```
3 while i < n                 log n + 1
4     for j = 1 to n           n log n
5        sum = sum + j         n log n
6     i = 2i                   log n
```

Then yes, you are correct in calculating the complexity. The complexity of the code is indeed`O(nlogn)`.

Edit:
Though I am curious what you are trying to do here. You are calculating the sum of 1st `n` elements `logn` times.

Hence the return value would be something like `n*(n+1)/2 * logn`

Comment: My assignment says  I can assume that every line takes one timeunit. The exercise is in identifying different sorts of statements (while/for) loops, giving them the correct "times" value. Big-Oh - notations is sufficient to solve the exercise (after adding the values). Thank you for your help PS: I added the "less-or-equal-to"-sign on line four